# Can electrons combine with neutrons to form negatively charged nuclei?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I've been wondering if electrons and protons could switch place such as constituent of an atom nuclei or that a proton "orbits" an electron instead ("inverted" hydrogen), are there forces on the quark level that prohibits such situations?

I do know charges do not affect the role because antimatter wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the strong residentual interaction which binds the neutrons and the protons in the core is unbelievably strong. Electrons don't feel the strong interaction(nor the strong residentual interaction) -> they would all be repulsed from each other and not form a 'nucleus'.

The closest thing you describe is a nucleus made of antiprotons and antineutrons( negatively charged ) surrounded by a cloud of protons but this would be extremely dangerous to play with.

Comment: It probably wouldn't last for more than a few picoseconds, either.